# How to include an axios interceptor in Quasar

Tags: axios, interceptor, quasar

I am currently working on a Quasar app that uses axios library. User is authenticated as usual by a token that, when expired, has to be renewed using a renewal token. I need an axios interceptor to filter status 401 so that I can ask for a new token and send the request again.
The interceptor is already coded, now the problem is that I don't know how to make Quasar use the plugin. The app that is currently in production, which is done with Vue 2, does it like this:

```
const _axios = axios.create(*config*);
axios.interceptors.request.use(.....);

Plugin.install = function(Vue, options) { .... }
Vue.use(Plugin)
export default Plugin;
```

Currently Quasar is based on Vue 3, and **Plugin** is deprecated, I know in Vue 3 the plugin should be included in the **/src/main.js** file like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp({})
app.use(myPlugin, {
  /* optional options */
})
```

But in Quasar there is no main.js file, I can't see an app.use anywhere, and don't know how to tell Quasar to use the plugin with the axios interceptor. I know there's a **quasar.conf.js** file that you can set to use Quasar plugins, such as **Dialog** for example,but I don't know if this file would be the place to make Quasar use the plugin I coded or how it should be done. I have not been able to find info on this subject, could someone please tell me how to make Quasar insert my plugin or point me to where I could find info about it? Thanks.